# Rake aborting, when a create_view migration file reached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to get some code running locally. But am running up against a problem when I run:

```
rake db:create db:migrate db:seed --trace
```

Using Postgres.

We have the gem scenic included which creates database views using create_view but for some reason when the migration reaches the migration file which creates a view I get the following error:

```
steve-vmn:ss steve$ rake db:create db:migrate db:seed --trace
RAILS_GROUPS is unset; defaulting to web,worker
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create
Database '22_development' already exists
Database '22_test' already exists
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:migrate
== 20170816124642 CreateStations: migrating ======================
-- create_view(:stations)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/steve/Ss/ss/db/views/stations_v01.sql
/Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/scenic-1.5.1/lib/scenic/definition.rb:10:in `read'
/Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/scenic-1.5.1/lib/scenic/definition.rb:10:in `to_sql'
```

Rake file:

```
class CreateStations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_view :stations
  end
end
```

I can't seem to find a similar error anywhere.

Comment: What are the contents of the `20170816124642_create_stations.rb` migration file? Based on the error, the scenic gem is attempting to open a file at `/Users/steve/Ss/ss/db/views/stations_v01.sql` that does not exist on your system.

Comment: Hey @Richard I've updated my answer to include the rake file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, and the scenic documentation, you need to define a SQL view in `db/views/stations_v01.sql`. See the following link for an example.

https://github.com/scenic-views/scenic#great-how-do-i-create-a-view

Answer (score 0):

See docs: https://github.com/scenic-views/scenic/blob/master/README.md

As mentioned in your error logs, there is no file exists: db/views/stations_v01.sql that comes after running the migration.

```
  rails generate scenic:view stations
  create  db/views/stations_v01.sql
  create  db/migrate/[TIMESTAMP]_create_stations.rb
```

After that

Edit the db/views/stations_v01.sql file with the SQL statement that defines your view.